# Ajax api call to Web api core

Tags: asp.net-ajax, asp.net-core-webapi, razor-pages

I have created a web API authenticate method using asp.net core. But while calling from razor page returning 400 status code. below are ajax request 
$("#btLogin").on('click', function () {

```
        $.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: 'https://localhost:xxxx/api/users/authenticate',
            type: "POST",
            //headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
             headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },                              
            data: ({
                username: $("#txtUserName").val(),
                password: $("#txtPassword").val()
            }),
            success: function (resp) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('userName', resp.User_nm);
                sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', resp.tokenString);
                authHeaders.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + resp.tokenString;                 
                location.href = "https://localhost:xxx/Home";
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });      
    });
```

May I know what is wrong in it ?

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue.Could you share your whole razor pages and web api action?

Comment: what you have given me is more than enough, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't POST using `JSONP`.It simply doesn't work that way, it creates a `<script>` element to fetch data which has to be a GET request.

Here is a working demo:

**For Razor Pages:**

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<form>    
        <div>
            <input id="txtUserName" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="txtPassword" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="btLogin" value="login" />
        </div>
</form>
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    $("#btLogin").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            //dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: 'https://localhost:44338/api/users/authenticate',
            type: "POST",
            //headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },                              
            data: ({
                username: $("#txtUserName").val(),
                password: $("#txtPassword").val()
            }),
            success: function (resp) {
                //...
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });      
    });
</script>
}
```

**For Web Api:**

Model:

```
public class Login
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("Authenticate")]
    public IActionResult Authenticate([FromForm]Login user)
    {
        //do your stuff...
    }
}
```

Be sure to configure your web api project to enable enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddMvc();

}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors(
        options => options.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
    );

    //...
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: services.AddMvc(); is not allowed in my configure so I have added services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false); on configure service is that okay ?

Comment: my ajax success function is not firing with same code, may i  know why ?

Comment: From your description,it seems you used asp.net core 3.x for your web api project,right?